# Document C++ macros when hiding files

Tags: c++, macros, doxygen

I am documenting a C++ project using `doxygen`. In this project, there are some macros that are correctly documented in the code. In my doxyfile, I specify that I don't want a *Files* tab this way:

```
SHOW_FILES = NO
```

The problem is that when doing this, I have no way of seeing the macro documentation, since it seems to be only accessible through the *Files* tab:

[image: Macros from Files tab]

What I would like is to be able to consult the macro documentation without making file documentation available. Is there a way I could do this?

I browsed the special commands and the configuration options and saw nothing about this. I tried the `@copydoc` flag, but only the body of the documentation is copied, which is not what I need (I need to move the documentation altogether).

---

Update : here is one of the macro, with its documentation:

```cpp
#ifndef NDEBUG
/*********************************************************************************************//**
 * @brief Standard assertion MACRO (with message attached)
 *
 * Asserts that `p_condition` is `true`. If you `#define` the `ABORT_ON_ERROR` flag, this
 * MACRO will also abort on a `false` condition. On assertion, a custom message defined by the
 * programmer will be printed out along with the assertion information.
 *
 * @param p_condition
 *      The condition to assert.
 * @param p_message
 *      The message to print.
 *
 *************************************************************************************************/
#define ASSERT_MSG(p_condition, p_message) cxinv::HandleAssert(cxinv::AssertLabel::ASSERTION, \
                                                               ( p_condition ),               \
                                                               #p_condition,                  \
                                                               __FILE__,                      \
                                                               __FUNCTION__,                  \
                                                               __LINE__,                      \
                                                               p_message                      \
                                                               )
#else
#define ASSERT_MSG(p_condition, p_message) ((void)0)
#endif // NDEBUG
```

Comment: Can you add a piece of documented macro from your project so that I can check?

Comment: One way would be to stop using macros ;-)

Comment: @Kozmotronik Sure! Just added an example.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I wish... I you have an alternative (to my example), I am all ears!

Comment: Is `#ifndef NDEBUG` condition true? If not, that macro will not be parsed by doxygen.

Comment: It is true for my debug build. If I activate the *Files* tab, I can read the documentation for the macro.

Comment: Do you use doxygen grouping? The macro documentation may not be displayed due to the lack of grouping. The fields must depend to something. This may be the reason that the macro doc is not displayed in somewhere else but only within the file tab. Do you see rest of the documentation other than macros though, i.e. function or variable documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put your macros in a group. This will add a modules tab:

```
    /**
    * @defgroup macros  Add macro group title here
    */
    
    /*********************************************************************************************//**
     * @brief Standard assertion MACRO (with message attached)
     * @ingroup macros
     *
...(cut off, see the rest above)
```